# filtering my search further

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to echo the results I want, how can I filter them further?

**example**, `search x100 y100`, currently get hundreds of results. I need to filter these results further so I only get those thats are marked hostile, pending or friendly

I have the following html form

```
<form action="xysearch.php" method="post">
     <label>X Coord
       <input type="text" name="x" />
      </label>
     <label>Y Coord
       <input type="text" name="y" />
      </label>
     <select name="term">
       <option value="Hostile">Hostile</option>
       <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
       <option value="Friendly">Friendly</option>
      </select>
     <input type="submit" value="Search" />
   </form>
```

what I need to add to the search query is a way to filter those results so only the option selected in the diplomacy dropdown are shown

My query thus far which is not working - I can get ALL the results, but not just the filtered ones.

```
<?php

$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$term = $_POST['term'];

mysql_connect ("localhost","host","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("d_base");

 $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (x BETWEEN $x -75 AND $x +75) AND (y BETWEEN $y -75 AND $y +75) ");
 $res2 = mysql_query("SELECT dip FROM my_table WHERE dip IN '%$term%' ORDER BY '%$term%' DESC  ");

    echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>City Name</th> <th>X</th> <th>Y</th> <th>Diplomacy</th> </tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res, $res2 )) {

// echo out the contents of each row into a table

    echo '<td>' . $row['city'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['x'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['y'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['dip'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";

// close table>

    echo "</table>";

    }

?>
```

I'm not too sure where i am going wrong as i can actually get results to echo, is just the filtering thats the issue.

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should have a look at [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114)

Comment: Hello, thank you for the advice, I understand the risk, however, the website that it is being for has only a few people with access to it. This access is protected by password. I'm sure as i learn more about php, i will adopt PDO Methods. again, thank for the warning and advice

Comment: If you don't want to go through PDO Methods, just use mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the [PHP definition of mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and it seems to accept only one result set, so if I'm correct, you are only iterating through the first result set, which is the unfiltered one.

`array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )`

Why aren't you filtering the result in a single query? It does seem like you are fetching items from a single table (my_table), right?

Here is a working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/caa62/1/0):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (x BETWEEN $x -75 AND $x +75) AND (y BETWEEN $y -75 AND $y +75) AND dip REGEXP '$term' ORDER BY dip DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res )) {
...
}
```

Notice that you'll have concatenate the different terms by an '|' (or) operator.

Comment: I have tried what you sent, (many thanks), it didn't work unfortunately. All results are from the same table but different columns.

Comment: Can you please paste in the rendered query? i.e: the one with the real values rather than variables? I'll get you a SQL Fiddle in a minute. Also, I've edited the query, the ORDER BY part should use a column name rather than a value.

Comment: I've changed the query a bit and added a working sqlfiddle, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`"SELECT dip FROM my_table WHERE dip IN '%".$term."%' ORDER BY '".$term."' DESC"`

Or if that doesn't work:

`"SELECT dip FROM my_table WHERE dip='".$term."' ORDER BY '".$term."' DESC"`

and yes, SQL injection :) You are VERY vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

A first glimpse of your code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res, $res2 )) {
```

isn't correct because $res2 SHOULD be a resulttype and not a result from a query.

The options are:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res, MYSQL_NUM )) {
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res, MYSQL_BOTH )) {
```

I guess you're trying to achieve something like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (x BETWEEN $x -75 AND $x +75) AND  (y BETWEEN $y -75 AND $y +75) AND dip LIKE '%$term%'");
```

This would mean code like this:

```
<?php

$x = $_POST['x'];
$y = $_POST['y'];
$term = $_POST['term'];

mysql_connect ("localhost","host","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("d_base");


 $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (x BETWEEN $x -75 AND $x +75) AND  (y BETWEEN $y -75 AND $y +75) AND dip LIKE '%$term%'");



    echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5'>";
    echo "<tr> <th>City Name</th> <th>X</th> <th>Y</th> <th>Diplomacy</th> </tr>";

// loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $res, MYSQL_ASSOC )) {

// echo out the contents of each row into a table

    echo '<td>' . $row['city'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['x'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['y'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['dip'] . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>";

// close table>

    echo "</table>";

    }

?>
```

For a better database, I think you SHOULD store the terms in a separate table and do some joining instead:

If you decide to do this, use a query in a way similar to this:

```
 $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table mt LEFT JOIN terms t ON (mt.term_id = t.id) WHERE (x BETWEEN $x -75 AND $x +75) AND  (y BETWEEN $y -75 AND $y +75) AND dip LIKE '%$term%'");
```

Another tip is to use PDO. It really isn't harder then using mysql_* - functions. In a way it's easier to create better and more readable code.